# Adding multiple keys and values to cookie - Javascript

Tags: javascript, cookies

I need help with making a cookie thats going to have a lot of different values. So far I have this.

```
function makeCookie(key, value) {
document.cookie= key + "=" + value + "; path=/";}

//event listener to kick off the cookie function
var style1button = document.getElementById('style1');
style1button.addEventListener('click',function ()
{makeCookie('style','style1')},false);

//event listener to kick off the cookie function
var style2button = document.getElementById('style2'); 
style2button.addEventListener('click',function(
{makeCookie('style','style2')},false);
```

I am going to be adding in more and I will end up needing to make a cookie more then one style, but I am not sure how to pass through multiple key,values into the same function I have setup. Or is it literally just making up new names instead of

```
makeCookie(key, value)
```

can I do

```
makeCookie(key1, value1, key2, value2......)
```

I apologize if this is easy, I am new at this. After looking at the document.cookie info from multiple sites, I am not able to find anything that makes sense.

Comment: Perhaps you should use `localStorage` instead, it is much easier to work with and can store more data than cookies https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API

Comment: you can write any cookie setting function you want. but setting `document.cookie` REPLACES whatever was there previously, so you can't do `doc.cook='a=b';doc.cook='c=d'`, and have a+c in there, you'll only have `c=d`

Comment: I mean you could have a function clear current cookies with `document.cookie = ""` then make your current function addCookie and change the `=` to `+=`.

Answer (score 0):

Though I do suggest switching to [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API), if you want to support variable arguments, I suggest you switch your argument to an object `{ key: "foo", value: "bar" }` and then use the array-like `arguments` object to iterate over however many are passed:

```
// I usually put a comment showing an example of the argument(s) when 
// allowing a variable number of arguments
function makeCookie(/* { key: "foo", value: "bar" }, { ... } */) {
   for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
      document.cookie= arguments[i].key + "=" + arguments[i].value + "; path=/";
   }
}

makeCookie({ key: "foo", value: "bar" });
makeCookie({ key: "style1", value: "styleValue" }, { key: "style2", value: "styleValue2" });
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a function for clearing cookies (if you want) and one for adding cookies:

```
function clearCookies () {
    document.cookie = "";
}

function addCookie (key, value) {
    document.cookie += key + "=" + value + "; path=/";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this:
makeCookie(key1, value1, value2, value3......)

Functions in JS basically has "arguments" object. So, to achieve the above feature your makeCookie function should look like below:

```
function makeCookie(){
   var key = arguments[0];
   var value;
   for (var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++) {
      var tempValue = arguments[i];
      //write a logic here to represent the multiple values into one value        
   }

   document.cookie= key + "=" + value + "; path=/";
}
```

Note: the above code assumes that you will always pass key as first argument while calling the function.